# How can I get rid of the c in $P(X>\epsilon+ c)\leq \exp(-\epsilon/c)$

Tags: probability, linear-algebra

I have a probability bound for some random variable $X$ that has the following structure
$$P(X>\epsilon+ c)\leq \exp(-\epsilon/c^2)$$

, where $\epsilon>0$ and $c>0$ is the variance of $X$. I would like to get rid of the $c$ on the left hand side, i.e. somehow bring it over to the upper bound, ideally as a multiplicative or within the $\exp$ expression.

At the same time, I would like to have a probability on $X\geq \eta$ for any $\eta \geq 0$, but just substituting $\eta=\epsilon +c$ doesn't help here since both are strictly larger then zero, right?

Answer (score 2):

How about defining a new constant $\eta = \epsilon + c$? That way, you get
\begin{equation}
P(X > \eta) \leq \exp(- (\eta - c)/c^2).
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, but at the same time I would like to have a probability on $X\geq \eta$ for any $\eta \geq 0$... just substituting $\eta=\epsilon +c$ doesn't help here since both are strictly larger then zero, right?